# Girsanov theorem conditions

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

If we have an adapted function $f(t)$ such that $\int_0^t f(s)ds\,<\infty$, then the Girsanov exponent can be defined:

$$
Z(t):=\exp\left( \int_0^t f(s)dW(s) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f^2(s)ds\right),  t \in [0,T]
$$

We require conditions for $Z(t)$ to be a true martingale (and Girsanov measure transformation to be applicable). The Novikov condition is sufficient and formulated as

$$
E\left[\exp\left( \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f^2(s)ds\right)\right]\,<\infty
$$

Note that there is an alternative condition specified in Shreve "Stochastic Calculus for Finance II", Theorem 5.4.1, p. 224. I've been taught that the Novikov condition is sufficient though.

Let us consider the following 4 cases:

1. $f(t)$ is a constant.
2. $f(t)$ is a continuos function of time.
3. $f(t)$ is a predicable random process.
4. $f(t)$ is a random process.

Am I correct in thinking that the Novikov condition must be met only for the last 2 cases? Sure, we can use it for deterministic functions too, but that's not necessary (?). Instead, we could get away with $\int_0^T f^2(s)ds\,<\infty$ or potentially $\int_0^\infty f^2(s)ds\,<\infty$ (which one?) However at least one source on the web that I found does actually apply Novikov's condition on a deterministic function: http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/390/Lecture10.pdf . Furthermore, it seems obvious that there are no conditions at all if $f(t)$ is a constant.

I would appreciate if someone could help me make sense out of this.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand your question. Of course you can apply Novikov condition whenever $f$ is deterministic. $\int^t_0f(s)^2\text{d}s<\infty$ for every $t$ is sufficient... when $f$ is a constant, this is just a geometric brownian motion and Novikov condition is satisfied. also, I am not sure if $4$ is allowed in a general setting. I believe $f$ needs to be previsible. Of course, this can mean $f$ may also be a function of the Brownian motion, but evaluating Novikov condition would be potentially difficult.

Comment: Hi lost1, the question is whether we can get away with other conditions (see "which one") in case 2 in particular.

Comment: but $\int^T_0f^2(s)\text{d}s$ is just Novikov's condition... because if the integral is finite, then the exponential of the exponential is finite?

Comment: Thanks Lost1, that makes sense. So then $\int_0^\infty f^2(s)ds\,<\infty$ is not needed. (In my lecture notes I do have the condition with the infinite upper limit though).